# Login looks like it works but no new Claims is given

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a login page called LoginTrial, the user enters the username and password and presses enter to log in.
The code below does successfully test the validity of username/password combos and returns an error if it does not exist in the table User.
However, if the combo of username/password is correct, the login looks to work, but it is as if i had not logged in at all, i don't see anything under: if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

I know it's a bad idea to not hash passwords, but this was made to test login features.

```
User appUser = dbs.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE username = {uid} AND password = {pw}").FirstOrDefault();

principal = null;

if (appUser != null)
{
    principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(
                        new Claim[] {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUser.Username),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, appUser.Role)
                        }, "Basic"
                    )
    );
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Start hashing (and salting) those passwords early in dev. What starts out as test code can easily make it into production in the work environment!

Comment: The code snippet above, where is it taken from? Usually claims are added before calling `HttpContext.SignInAsync`. An alternative is to use a custom implementation of `IClaimsTransformation`.